# Perforce unshelve command is not returning the shelved CL's changes

Tags: jenkins, batch-processing, perforce

I have written a jenkins script to unshelve perforce changelist and then run commands on it.

p4 -c %my_client_name% unshelve -f -s %SHELVED_CL1% %perforce_path%

this when runs gives me a notification that

- "unshelved, opened for edit"
but, when i check the file, it does not have those shelved CL's changes.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening..

Comment: Is the `-c` a typo? If not, it should be followed by a client name.

Comment: @sferencik Yes it is followed by a client_name.

Comment: Does the file have other changes, but just not those from that shelf? Does it have no changes at all? What does 'p4 opened' say at that point? Does this only happen with one particular client? With one particular shelf? With one particular file? What happens if you run the commands interactively, rather than via Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible explanations:

1) You're looking at the wrong local file.  Run "p4 -c CLIENT where FILE" to see the mapping for that file, and then look at that local path *on the machine where your script is running*.

2) The unshelve operation gave you some extra info/warning/error that your script is eating (or that you omitted from your question because it didn't sound relevant).  Likely messages would include something along the lines of `must resolve @=SHELVED_CL` or `unable to write LOCAL_FILE`.  If you got a `must resolve` message it means the file is already open with local changes and you need to run `p4 resolve` to merge the local changes with the shelved changes.  If there was an error about being unable to write the file the error will probably include an explanation in the form of an OS message (access denied, no permission, etc).  As a rule of thumb, if there's some sort of error message, you should figure out what it means and then fix the thing it's complaining about.